# How can we prove this property

Tags: probability

If $A$ and $B$ are independent, the same holds true for $A$ and $B^c$. How can we prove this ?
 $$P(A \cap B^c)= P(A)P(B^c)$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $P(A\cap B^c) = P(A) - P(A\cap B) = P(A) - P(A)P(B) = P(A)(1- P(B)) = P(A)P(B^c)$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are two independent events, then $A$ and $B^c$ are also independent.

$$P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)P\left(\frac{B^c}{A}\right)=P(A)P(B^c)$$